# php preg_replace to find this value = }},]}}

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to use PHP `preg_replace` to find this value = `}},]}}` and replace it with this other value = `}}]}}`

Something like this but I don't know how to use it:

```
$cadena = $array;
echo  preg_replace('/}}[,]]}}/', '}}]}}', $cadena);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to escape your curly braces and brackets, as they have syntactic meaning in regular expressions.  This works fine:

```
echo preg_replace('/\}\},\]\}\}/', '}}]}}', "Hello}},]}}World");
```

But it doesn't sound like you need to do regexes...you're describing the string as if it's static...so, why not just do:

```
str_replace('}},]}}','}}]}}')
```

Comment: I have this value inside and array "viewCount":"254697392"}},]}} and i want to remove the comma so i can get this "viewCount":"254697392"}}]}}

Comment: It looks like it's JSON, so why don't you just use json_decode() and then loop through the data and get the property you need without trying to manually parse the string?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired using str_replace instead? might be easier,

```
$cadena = str_replace("}},]}}","}}]}}",$cadena);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this php thing :)

Comment: I have this value inside and array "viewCount":"254697392"}},]}} and i want to remove the comma so i can get this "viewCount":"254697392"}}]}}